# Adding writing below picture

Tags: html, css

How can I add writing below picture in a DIV container? I would like to add centered, below the picture, some text that will move with the hover effect, like growing in size and having white background. Also, why do I keep having extra space in the right of the webpage?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

  #container {
    width: 720px;
  }
  .panel {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  }

  .panel .hover {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;

    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);

    -o-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  }
  .panel .hover:hover {

    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
   padding-bottom: 90px;

  }

</style>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2+.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C1.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
 <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C2.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2+W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C1W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C2W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I was looking for that one. :-D In this case, apply the hover effect to the container, and the text should size with it.

Comment: Have you tired the simplest answer and tried adding some text after your images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the text inside the div with the hover class like so.

```css
#container {
    width: 720px;
  }
  .panel {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  }

  .panel .hover {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;

    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);

    -o-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  }
  .panel .hover:hover {

    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
   padding-bottom: 90px;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<body>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2.jpg" width="110%" height="150%">Some Text</div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2+.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C1.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
 <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C2.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="B2+W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C1W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
  <div class="panel"><div class="hover"><img src="C2W.jpg" width="110%" height="150%"></div></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```